# How can I determine why my phone won't sleep?

Tags: standby

When my phone won't go to sleep, what is the best way to trouble-shoot what the problem and/or offending app is?

(In my case I am running CyanogenMod, and so I don't know if the solution will be the same or different than for stock Android)

Comment: What version of CyanogenMod?

Comment: Sorry - CM 6.1.0-DS

Comment: In stock Android, there is a developer setting "never sleep when plugged in". Is that turned on?

Comment: I couldn't find a similar option in CyanogenMod, but it could be there somewhere.

Comment: The setting Al mentioned was found under `Settings -> Applications -> Development` on my Galaxy S until the 2.2.1 update, check there if you have it.

Comment: Thanks - just found it.  In my case, it is not checked and thus isn't the culprit, but it's nice to know where to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look at which apps are runnng (including services).  Then use Titanium Backup to freeze on of those apps (exclude regular system apps/services, unless you've determined nothing else is the culprit) and see if your problem stops.  If you haven't found the offender, un-freeze and try another.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are there other apps like Titanium Backup that can freeze an app?

Comment: I'm not sure.  There are definitely other apps that do backups and uninstalls. So you could always back up the app, uninstall it, and restore it if it's not the problem.  Of course, you can screw up your system if you mess with a system app (though not permanently as the device/filesystem/etc. will be fine).

Answer (score 1):

When your phone wont go to sleep, check for wakelock using apps. Programs like "Wakelock detector" will help you to do that. Good luck!

Reference: [Wakelock](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/wakelock/info) , [Wakelock detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector)